# Why is the mitzvah to love the convert the one that is most often repeated in the Torah?

Tags: number, conversion-to-judaism, mitzvah, pentateuch-chumash

While I have no exact count, I read somewhere (don't recall if it was Ramba"m or similar source) that loving the convert is the one mitzvah that is repeated most often in the Torah. If this is true, why? If I'm mistaken, please tell me which oone is the most repeated.

Comment: My sister was turned down for a shidduch by a mother who 'would not have her son date the daughter of a convertess'. I have heard from friends of mine who have a convert father that he has not always been treated with the reespect he deserves. Perhaps we are reminded of this over and over because there is an innate tendency for us to mistreat converts.

Comment: One of my friends converted many years ago. I did not support her conversion, but she did it, anyway. She has proven my assumption to be wrong. She is more meticulous than I, and I have had great esteem for her.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36192/4682 :D

Comment: Large amount of overlap: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/which-mitzvah-is-repeated-the-most-times-in-the-chumash

Comment: Agreed that there is a lot of overlap. I shall leave the decision to close as duplicate to voters. It's too close a call for me to decide either way.

Answer (score 2):

Hashem knew it's the mitzvah that would be violated the most as the makeup and appearance of the Jewish nation would vary so widely in the diaspora. The concept of what a Jew looks like was irrelevant then and now, yet the prejudice against the other nations would always spread.

Comment: Interesting. Any source for this, or is it your own thought?

Comment: Agreed - it s a credible answer, but I would appreciate source on this thought. Thanks