# Why is "ahavas haGer" commanded at least 36 times?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

We know that even in respect of gerim tzadikkim, many born Jews were distracted by concerns like "yichus"/race/background/minhagim and value those aspects of personality more than the middot and Torah of the ger, as is common in the chinuch/shidduch world. And we do need a reminded that "for you were strangers in Egypt". But if we would not listen to Hashem (chas veshalom), how would mentioning it 36 times help, specifically with this mitzvah?

Comment: see also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38013/why-is-the-mitzvah-to-love-the-convert-the-one-that-is-most-often-repeated-in-th and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/which-mitzvah-is-repeated-the-most-times-in-the-chumash

Comment: Thanks, but those don't answer my question. They do not explain why this particular mitzvah warrant so many more mentions and what that is supposed to do to us.

Comment: It's to reinforce the importance of this particular mitzvah. Fact is, people who break 'small' commandments wouldn't think of breaking 'big' ones.

Comment: רַבִּי אוֹמֵר, ...... וֶהֱוֵי זָהִיר בְּמִצְוָה קַלָּה כְבַחֲמוּרָה, שֶׁאֵין אַתָּה יוֹדֵעַ מַתַּן שְׂכָרָן שֶׁל מִצְוֹת. וֶהֱוֵי מְחַשֵּׁב הֶפְסֵד מִצְוָה כְּנֶגֶד שְׂכָרָהּ, וּשְׂכַר עֲבֵרָה כְנֶגֶד הֶפְסֵדָהּ.

What is the the reward & what is the loss to the mitzvah?

Comment: Why do you assume it is mentioned that many times, that it is meant to help?