# Accept that you're a non-Jew or follow your heart?

Tags: gentiles, conversion-to-judaism

If a non-Jew sincerely longs to keep and fulfill the Torah with all its commands and prohibitions (mitzvot) in the same way as a Jew would— if someone identifies himself more with his Jewish fellow man instead of non-Jewish fellow man—

What should he do?

Should he just accept his divine purpose in this world, stick to the Noahide laws? become a righteous convert? or do something else?

Comment: How is this a question? If a person sincerely wants to convert to Judaism, then go ahead and do it. The person that you describe is the definition of a righteous convert to Judaism.

Comment: @sabbahillel I agree, but I heard this story one doesn't has to do so, because his purpose in this world would differ. So I asked it anyways, so I could advice a friend of mine.

Comment: @Levi So that you could advise your friend? Have him talk to a Rabbi. Why isn’t this psak seeking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion: If G-d really wanted me to be a Jew (and observe mitzvot), why was I not born into a Jewish family](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36145/conversion-if-g-d-really-wanted-me-to-be-a-jew-and-observe-mitzvot-why-was-i)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @sabbahillel in the comments to the OP, if a non-Jew sincerely wants to convert to Judaism, he may do so.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36145/conversion-if-g-d-really-wanted-me-to-be-a-jew-and-observe-mitzvot-why-was-i). "If G-d really wanted me to be a Jew (and observe mitzvot), why was I not born into a Jewish family?" Check out the answers there; you might find what you're looking for.

Kol tuv.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. He didn't ask if a non-Jew *may* convert to Judaism. He asked if a non-Jew *should* convert to Judaism. Your first paragraph does not address this. Your second paragraph is "[link only](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3414/13438)" as it just points the reader to somewhere else to find the answer. If you do in fact think that the two questions are basically the same then you can flag/vote to close this question as a duplicate rather than posting an answer which just points to the other question.

Comment: @Alex I agree with the points you've brought up, in retrospect. I did not think this answer through very well, tbh. I appreciate the feedback. Someone pinged this answer a few days ago and had it come up to the top of the feed.